# Avoiding multiple API calls in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to improve my ANGULAR application performance, by avoiding multiple calls to the same API.

**Scenario 1** : Same API (without params) gets called in multiple components.

**For eg: GetAllFlowers();**

This API is going to return the same Data everytime we are calling from different component.

**Scenario 2:** Same API (parameter changes based on the functionality) gets called in multiple components multiple times.

**For eg: GetFlowerType(1);**

This API is getting called twice at the same time with same parameter.

How can we avoid the above scenarios.

P.S: I'm a new bee to angular.

I tried Behavior subject. But No luck.

I am expecting that GetAllFlowers() should be called only once .
When there is a new call from different component for the same API, It should not trigger the API

Comment: Take a look at Service Worker, specifically look for [data groups](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#datagroups) - I think that's what you need.

Comment: I highly recommend to search for `shareReplay`. Read f. e. this: https://dev.to/this-is-angular/how-caching-data-in-angular-with-rxjs-27mj